# Django dealing with bootstrap form

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have this form:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="{% url     'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
      Sign in
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    <label class="checkbox pull-left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
    Remember me
    </label>

</form>
```

It has bootstrap classes. I used to have this form:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

  </form>
```

But i was really ugly so i changed it. The problem is that in the  new form i have no idea how to implement the authentification of django like i used to do in the ugly version of the form (this one worked fine, i used to write the username and password of the user that was saved in the auth_table of django and it logged in without problems)

But now with the prettier version i don´t know how to do that. I looked around but nothing helps.

Any advice will be really appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

Im using this in my url for this view:

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name':'login.html'}, name = 'login'),
```

that´s why i was rendering the form in the ugly way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customize  the  fiels of the form :

add attrs like class ,placeholder  (all html attrs )

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput().attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Usuario' })
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput().attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Password' })
```

Comment: ok. Now i just have to render the page in the template like this: "form.as_p"??

Comment: yes or Customizing the form template   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template